# Oracle DB connections increases after an IIS recycle

Tags: windows, vb.net, iis, oracle19c, application-monitoring

Web applications double in Oracle database connections after the IIS is recycled on the Windows 2019 web server. This is occurring during off-hours with nobody on the system. It's a VB.net application using ODP.net to connect to the database. How can I determine what is creating these numerous database connections? Is there a monitoring tool that will help capture the issue?

I set the expire_time in the sqlnet.ora for the database to terminate the connections as well as setup profiles to terminate idle connections however that we not prevent the vast amount of connections after an IIS recycle.

Comment: Sounds like the original connections may not be getting closed when IIS recycles. If these are really all new connections, then you've done about everything you can from the DB side of things. Anything else has pretty much got to be related to the application or its connection pool. You'll need to understand if this is expected application behavior on startup or not, then troubleshoot with the developers or vendor for the app to correct the problem.

Comment: Are all use of connections and database queries wrapped in a using block?

Comment: Did you observe the connections go back to normal after a while? IIS application pool recycle does keep the old worker processes for a short period of time by default and if you don’t like that you can disable overlapping recycle in IIS configuration.

Comment: @LexLi - How do you disable overlapping recycle in IIS configuration? I would like to try that. Also the connections do go back to normal after sometime.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/#configuration

Comment: @NateHimmons It is vital to use Using blocks, as Albert D. Khalil [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089419/oracle-db-connections-increases-after-an-iis-recycle#comment137667494_78089419) earlier. That is the *first* thing to check. (It is necessary to call `.Dispose()` on the commands and connections. Also, you must not have an application-scoped database connection - create a connection, perform the query, then immediately dispose of the unmanaged resources, such as the connection.)

Comment: @NateHimmons ... [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) calls Dispose for you, but you could use a Try structure and put the Dispose in the Finally section, as shown in the docs for Using.

Comment: How did you set up Oracle DB connections? Will the number of connections return to normal after a while?

Comment: @LexLi - I tried to disable overlapping in IIS Configuration and that didn't work. I created a .bat file that stopped the default pool for 2 minutes and during that time I seen all the connections terminated then once the pool was started the number of connections began to increase 20 to 30 per minute.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I don't have access to the code so I can't check if it's closing their connections correctly. :( I just think it's weird the connection are growing after a IIS restart. It's like all the apps on the webservers were holding a bunch of connections during the restart.

Comment: @NateHimmons You'll have to contact whoever does have access to the code.

Comment: Like Andrew commented, now you explored all options but the code itself. Time to escalate to the developers to check if they made mistakes.